# I made line graph using ggplot2 and transformed to PDF file. it has occured error in visual

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, linegraph

I made line graph using ggplot2 and transformed to PDF file. it has occured error in visual..

(1) original graph

[image]

(2) after transformed to PDF

[image]

```
be1<- read.csv("groupbe.csv")
str(be1)
be1
be1<-be1 %>% mutate(temp.fc = factor(temp))
be1 <- transform(be1,sample = factor(sample,levels = c("Lubricant (Viscous liquid)","Lubricant (Aerosol)","Grease (Semisolid)","Remover (Aerosol)")))

be1 %>% ggplot(aes(x = temp.fc, y = conc,group = sample, color = sample, linetype = sample)) +
  geom_line(lwd=2)+ scale_linetype_manual(values=c("dashed", "dotted","solid","dotdash"))+
  geom_point(size = 3.6, shape = 19)+
  theme_classic()+scale_y_log10(limits=c(0.2,10^3.477122221111))+ labs(x="Temperature (℃)", y="Concentrations (ppm, w/w)")+
  theme(axis.title = element_text(family = "serif", face = "bold", hjust = 0.5, size = 15, color = "black"))+
  theme(legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = "black"), legend.box.margin = margin(1, 1, 1, 1))+
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 13, family="serif"))+
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  theme(legend.key.width = unit(2.4, 'cm'))+
  theme(text=element_text(family="serif",  size=15))+
  theme(legend.position = c(0.8,0.85))
```

Comment: Hoe exactly did you "transform it to a pdf file?

Comment: Add the code which you have used to save plot to pdf file.

Comment: @MrFlick ah...use "Export" function, -> "copy to clipboard" copy as "metafile" -> "copy plot" and paste in MS word. after transformed to PDF file..

Comment: @rj-nirbhay sorry I didnt use code for transformed pdf file. as mentioned before,  "Export" function, -> "copy to clipboard" copy as "metafile" -> "copy plot" and paste in MS word. after transformed to PDF file..

Comment: So you are going from metafile right into Word? Because A windows metafile isn't a PDF as I understand it. I don't think there's a way to save a PDF directly to a clipboard. You can use `ggsave()` to write the PDF to a file first, and them place it in Word. Or make it clear you are working with metafiles here and not PDFs.

Comment: @MrFlick I usually use that way(going from metafile right into MSWORD). 
Actually, there are 2 pictures more in article. but only this picture has error.. 
anyway I appreciate you to try solve my problem :)